# Artifacts at particular edges after Subdivision modifier

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, artifacts, loop

So, the problem is basically visible at the pictures. The edges (the vertical one at the corner and the horizontal one going all the way to the back) seem "pinched" after adding subdivision surface modifier. What's strange is that the vertical one starts to behave abnormally in 1/3, where it connects to the horizontal one.

[image: Artifacts]
[image: Topology front]

As you can see there is no such problem at the back with the vertical edges, however the horizontal edge is still wrong.

[image: Back]
[image: Back topology]

I've tried creating loop cuts to make the bent more round (as it is at the back) and make the vertical edge look better, but nothing really changed. I've also tried the loopcuts to fix the horizontal one with the same effect (or lack of any). I've read that weighted edge creases might help, but I'm not sure where and how to apply them in my case.

Thanks in advance to anyone trying to help me. I'm still a noob in 3D modelling, so go easy on me :D

Comment: Thanks to whoever helped me by linking to another question. It was in fact a problem with inverted faces.

Comment: Glad to be of help, good luck with your project :)